# Batch file taking a long time to run Stuck on error

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run  this simple script (Below)but it takes it forever to run. I get an error: the rpc server in unavailable.  then it sits there for a long time.  It will finally finish but takes a long time.  How can I add something to the script to make it quit looking on errors and move on to the next device?

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I in (C:\Users\owner\Downloads\listt.txt) do call :pinger %%I goto :eof
:pinger
echo %TIME% >> ping_09_28_17.txt
ping -n 1 %1 >> ping_09_28_17.txt
wmic /user:username /password:XXXXXXXX /node:%1 computersystem get username >> ping_09_28_17.txt
:: DONE
```

Comment: The `GOTO :eof` will do nothing as you are actually passing it as an argument to your ping subroutine.  If the ping is not successful the errorlevel will be set to 1.  If that is true then don't do the WMIC command.

Comment: Sorry you are dealing with a newbe  so if I put in  "IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO"  what do I need to make it start the next device in the list and not exit?

Comment: would I just put "IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :NEXT?

Comment: I just realized it is the Wmic command that the slowness is coming from not the ping